# How to customize the attachment file name in ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

I have a file which returns a pdf attachment as an output. I am using wicked pdf to generate this pdf.

```
    def generate_pdf
        render pdf: "#{@user.name}",
                       template: 'api/v1/doctors/get_report_4.html.erb',
                       :page_size => 'Letter',
                       layout: false, disposition: 'attachment',
                       :margin => {bottom: @margin_bottom, top: @margin_top, left: @margin_left, right: @margin_right},
                       wkhtmltopdf: %x(bundle exec which wkhtmltopdf).to_s.strip.presence || %x(which wkhtmltopdf).to_s.strip}

end
```

But while calling this API. I am getting the attachment with name "response.pdf" instead of username.pdf. Please help me with this.

Comment: Are you sure `@user` is set before `generate_pdf` is called?

Comment: Yes. Even that @user actually won't matter, because I am seeing the response(logs) in the terminal where rails server is running as Irfan.pdf but the pop-up to save the file is coming as response.pdf. :(

Comment: Did you try using `send_data` or `send_file` methods instead of `render`?

Comment: Yes tried with send_data , but the issue is still the same.